# Lisp - Type Error in Do Form When Reading from File

Tags: types, io, char, common-lisp, sbcl

[SBCL] I'm trying to read char-by-char from a text file that looks like this:

```
:table
E E E E E
E C C C E
E E E E E
```

My code (some omitted for clarity):

```
(defun read-txt (path)
   (with-open-file str path :direction :input
                   :if-exists :supersede)
     (let ((a nil)
           (form read-line str))
        (case form
          (otherwise (do* ((char (read-char str nil) (read-char str nil))
                           (count 0 (if (char= char #\Newline) (1+ count) count)))
                          ((null char) a)))))))
```

Gives me an error along the lines of "The value NIL is not of type CHARACTER." The backtrace isn't useful at all, even after setting debug to 3. All it tells me is that I called read-txt and its argument is a file path.

When I print each character in the file, none of them are NIL. I don't get an error if I use char= in do's main body. The code compiles without errors or warnings.

Comment: Please copy and paste all code and error messages. Your current code will produce a different error: the `let` clause for `form` is broken.

Comment: You really should not indent by manually. The editor should do it or Lisp itself. Here the indentation is wrong. The part after WITH-OPEN-FILE which are the parameters need to be in parentheses. Your code only has a closing parenthesis, the open parentheses is missine. Adjust your code and reindent the code - but nit manually, use a tool. Indentation is important and there is no way it can be done reliably without a tool.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to paste from emacs' clipboard to Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[original response](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnlisp/comments/6krk7o/weird_type_error_in_do_form/)

A `do` form's variable list is evaluated before its end form each iteration. The last char in the file was `nil`. Since I was calling `char=` in the varlist, `nil` was passed to it just before `do` would have terminated.

`Do`'s body is evaluated after the end form, which is why a `char=` in the body didn't cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun read-txt (path)
  (with-open-file str path :direction :input
    :if-exists :supersede)
  (let ((a nil)
        (form read-line str))
    (case form
      (otherwise (do* ((char (read-char str nil) (read-char str nil))
                       (count 0 (if (char= char #\Newline) (1+ count) count)))
                      ((null char) a))))))
```

This is what you code looks like when correctly indented.

While compiling this code SBCL says:

```
; in: DEFUN READ-TXT
;     (WITH-OPEN-FILE STR PATH :DIRECTION :INPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE)
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   during macroexpansion of (WITH-OPEN-FILE STR PATH ...). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS*
;   to intercept.
;   
;    error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO WITH-OPEN-FILE:
;      invalid number of elements in
;        STR
;      to satisfy lambda list
;        (STREAM SB-IMPL::FILESPEC &REST SB-IMPL::OPTIONS):
;      at least 2 expected, but got a non-list

;     (LET ((A NIL) (FORM READ-LINE STR))
;       (CASE FORM
;         (OTHERWISE
;          (DO* (#
;                #)
;               (# A)))))
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   The LET binding spec (FORM READ-LINE STR) is malformed.

;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA READ-TXT
;         (PATH)
;       (BLOCK READ-TXT
;         (WITH-OPEN-FILE STR PATH :DIRECTION :INPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE)
;         (LET ((A NIL) (FORM READ-LINE STR))
;           (CASE FORM (OTHERWISE #)))))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable PATH is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 2 ERROR conditions
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

Since the code does not even compile and has several syntactical errors, it is hard to speculate what errors one could see when running different code...

What is clear though: `char=` expects a character. But in your loop it can get a `NIL` argument, which is not a character. If the code would actually be working at all...